# 2D complex-valued vector initialisation

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>    

using namespace std;

vector<vector<complex> > matrix;
```

which is meant to be a 2D vector with complex values.  The size of the structure is not known at compile time so I think a vector is a reasonable choice?

I'm using Qt.. a search didn't reveal any matrix classes.  Is there an alternative I should use?  Assuming a 2D vector is a good choice.  How come this happens on build:

I get the following error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 
       'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'
error:   expected a type, got 'complex'
```

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem with vectors of vectors is that there's nothing constraining each sub-vector to be of the same size, so you can end with jagged arrays if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`complex` is a templated class, so you need to specialize it. I guess that you want either `float` or `double`:

```
vector<vector<complex<double> > > matrix;
```